# How to add a space (' ') after the 10th character in a string in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Hey PowerShell noobie here.

Please can somebody point me in the right direction on how to add a space ' ' after then 10th character in the string below:

```
$var = '01/03/202012:00:00'
```

The finished result should look like this:

```
$var = '01/03/2020 12:00:00'
```

Thanks a heap!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
$var = '01/03/202012:00:00'.insert(10, ' ')
```

[image]

And, for future reference, you can see the list of string functions with something like... (`gm` is the built-in alias for the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) cmdlet)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex way.  With -replace, "$&" means the whole match.  It's buried in the docs somewhere.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#substitutions  I still haven't come up with a use for all of them.

```
'01/03/202012:00:00' -replace '^..........','$& '

01/03/2020 12:00:00
```

Or with a scriptblock in PS 6 or 7:

```
'01/03/202012:00:00' -replace '^..........', { "$_ " }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a beginner I will also point out the obvious solution:

```bsh
$var = '01/03/202012:00:00'
# from index 0 take 10 characters
$firstPart = $var.Substring(0,10)
# from index 10 take the rest of the string
$secondPart = $var.Substring(10)
# join the two parts with a space in between
$result = "$firstPart secondPart"
```